# pandas need to merge two data frames by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, first many more rows than the second, and has a column like:

```
A
A
B
B
C
C
```

Second is like:

```
A, blue, 1
B, red, 2
C, yellow, 3
```

I want to merge them so that I get one dataframe that looks like:

```
A, blue, 1
A, blue, 1
B, red, 2
B, red, 2
C, yellow, 3
C, yellow, 3
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df_left.merge(df_right, left_on=left_column_name, right_on=right_column_name)

Check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Did that work for you? I tried it, did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want all the keys in one dataframe, so you should use merge with the how='left' parameter, as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], columns=['alpha'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'blue', 1], ['B', 'red', 2], ['C', 'yellow', 3]], columns=['alpha', 'color', 'idx'])
    print(df.merge(df2, how='left', on='alpha'))
```

outputs

```
  alpha   color  idx
0     A    blue    1
1     A    blue    1
2     B     red    2
3     B     red    2
4     C  yellow    3
5     C  yellow    3
```